# On the Product Formula for Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

[image]I came across a theorem (in the image above) on page 21 of Pierre Bremaud's Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes 1st ed. 2020, that made me wonder whether there something wrong in the statement thereof.

In the proof, the author seems to use the fact that $P(Y = y, Z = z) = P(Y = y)P(Z = z)$ for all $y \in F$ and $z \in G$. This does not seem immediate from the hypotheses in the statement of the Theorem, unless independence is assumed and this makes me wonder whether it was unintentionally omitted or the above conditions are indeed sufficient for this 'factorisation' of the probabilities above.

For instance, if we let Z = Y, with $v = w = Id$ then the Theorem would seem to imply that $E[Y^2] = E[Y]^2$ which does not hold in complete generality to the best of my knowledge (taking $Y$ to be a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $\frac{1}{2}$ seems to be a counterexample).

I would be grateful for any comment on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If https://i.imgur.com/KSRG2hx.png is the proof you refer to (which it would have been good to post!), there is no reliance on what you say. The proof asserts that two sums are equal, but not that the summands are pointwise equal. (Also, the proof does seem to have a typo, where one sum should be over $z\in G$, not $z\in F$.)

Comment: Even so, I still don't see why this should be the case in what seems to be (almost) complete generality. For instance, if we let Z = Y, with $v = w = Id$ then the Theorem would seem to imply that $E[Y^2] = E[Y]^2$ which does not hold in complete generality to the best of my knowledge(taking $Y$ to be a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $\frac{1}{2}$).

Comment: I was just trying to clarify your observation, but yes, it looks wrong to me, too, though I’m not a probabilist and don’t know if the countability could come into play. From what I can see of the book on Google Books, the author applies the theorem in a situation with independent random variables, so maybe that hypothesis should have been in the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is only true under the assumption that $v$ and $w$ are independent (indeed, the truth of the statement for *any* $F, G$ is the definition of independence). Now, I do not have the book in front of me, just the screen shot, so maybe the author makes some independence assumption elsewhere, but this is clearly false as stated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have attached the exact statement of the proof in the question.

Comment: @PantelisT. I saw the proof from the screenshot in the comment. Unless there some surrounding discussion, this is just plain wrong.